# Create UI components on page load

Tags: oracle-adf

I am currently working on oracle adf task flows and regions and I want to create and update some UI components on page load and for this I am using method call activity as default.The problem is that I am getting null values  following is my code in the bean that executes on the method call.

```
package view;

import javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.output.RichOutputText;

public class testBean {
    public testBean() {
    }

    public String testMethod() {
        // Add event code here...



        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        UIViewRoot root = facesContext.getViewRoot();


        RichOutputText text =    ( RichOutputText )root.findComponent( "r1:ot1" );

        text.setValue( "Adding text on run time" );

        return "product";

    }
}
```

The set value method returning me null may be it is because the fragment product.jsff which is the view activity is not initiated and the output text with ot1 returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better approach to achieve the setting of value is to have a property in your bean say: textValue and then bind the value attribute of your ot1 with the property of the bean.

```
class TestBean{
  private String textValue;

  public String testMethod() {
    textValue = "Adding text on run time";
  }

  public String getTextValue(){
    return textValue;
  }
}
```

Your JSPX would be:

```
<af:outputText id="ot1" value=#{beanName.textValue}" />
```

Comment: The way you told me is also correct but the problem is that I am working with a bounded taskflow.Any ways my another question is that I am generating the ui dynamically on run time but the problem is that the UI components are not clickable and I am unable to click on the ui components, the code is as follows.

Comment: please start a new query, that way it will help you get answers quickly.